# Using methods and constructors to construct a basic calculator

Tags: java, calculator

I am trying to come up with a simple basic calculator but am supposed to work with the following constructors and methods:

```
simpleCalc();
simpleCalc(double op1, double op2);
double add();
double add(double op1, double op2);
double mult();
double mult(double op1, double op2);
double exp();
double exp(double op1, double op2);
void show();
void show(int dp);
```

I have written down some working code and I just want to know if am doing the right thing.

**MyClass.java**

```
package basicjavacalculator;

public class MyClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO code application logic here
simpleCalc sc = new simpleCalc();
sc.show();

 }

}
```

**simpleCalc.java**

```
package basicjavacalculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class simpleCalc {

double add(){
return 0;
}

double mult(){
return 0;
}

double exp(){
return 0;
}

simpleCalc(){

}

void show(){

Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("=================Welcome to SimpleCalcDemo=================");
System.out.println("\n");

System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
double op1 = userInput.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
double op2 = userInput.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter operation to perform (+,x,^):");
String operation= userInput.next();

if(operation.equals("+")){
    System.out.println(add(op1, op2));
}

else if (operation.equals("x")){
    System.out.println(mult(op1, op2));
} 

else if (operation.equals("^")){
    System.out.println(exp(op1, op2));
}
else{
System.out.println("The operation is not valid.");

}

}

double add(double op1, double op2){
return op1 + op2;
}

double mult(double op1, double op2){
return op1 * op2;        
}

double exp(double op1, double op2){
double result = 1;
while (op2 > 0){
    result = result * op1;
    op2--;
}

return result;
}

}
```

Comment: I have rollbacked the last edit, not sure why OP chose to remove the original code...

Comment: I've voted to put this on hold because the implementation is incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

This can be simplified:

```
double exp(double op1, double op2){
double result = 1;
while (op2 > 0){
    result = result * op1;
    op2--;
}

return result;
}
```

You should be using the [`Math.pow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) method:

```
double exp(double op1, double op2){
    return Math.pow(op1, op2);
}
```

Also, you should use proper indentation to help you read and understand your code better, which will help prevent bugs.

This doesn't do anything:

```
simpleCalc(){

}
```

It is best to remove code like this to make your project easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: i understand simpleCalc() does not do anything but i have to use it in my code

Answer (score 2):

If you only scan for `int` operands, then you should probably store those operands in `int` variables.

Your `exp(…, …)` function fails with negative or non-integer exponents.  The simple solution would be to use `Math.pow(…, …)`, but at the least you should validate your inputs to avoid returning incorrect results.

The no-argument forms of `add()`, `mult()`, and `exp()` are useless, and should be eliminated.

`show()` isn't quite the right name, as there is no corresponding `hide()` operation.

The `SimpleCalc` object maintains no state, so there is no need to instantiate an object, and all of the functions should be declared `static`.  There is also no need to make another class just to contain the `main()` function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleCalc {
    /**
     * Suppresses the default constructor.
     */
    private SimpleCalc() {}

    public static void run() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("=================Welcome to SimpleCalcDemo=================\n\n");

        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        int op1 = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        int op2 = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter operation to perform (+,x,^):");
        String operation = userInput.next();

        if (operation.equals("+")) {
            System.out.println(add(op1, op2));
        } else if (operation.equals("x")){
            System.out.println(mult(op1, op2));
        } else if (operation.equals("^")){
            System.out.println(exp(op1, op2));
        } else {
            System.out.println("The operation is not valid.");
        }
    }

    private static long add(int op1, int op2) {
        return (long)op1 + op2;
    }

    private static long mult(int op1, int op2) {
        return (long)op1 * op2;        
    }

    private static long exp(int op1, int op2) {
        if (op2 < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative exponents are not supported");
        }
        long result = 1;
        while (op2 > 0){
            result = result * op1;
            op2--;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleCalc.run();
    }
}
```